# pointer-events: none except for the click event

Tags: javascript, css, svg, click, pointer-events

End Goal: I'm trying to manipulate an element inside an svg from a library I'm using. The element has drag and drop capabilities, but also shows a pop-up on click. I would like to disable the drag and drop but still allow the click.

I know I can use pointer-events: none on the element to disable the drag and drop, but then I need the click functionality back.

Is there a way to do this in css or javascript?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please read [ask]. Namely, considering your question, you might want to provide a *runnable* [mcve], stating in clear: input, current output, expected output. Not having an example makes it significantly harder for people who could help to help, so they just skip to easier to answer questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.